# Silent Network Authentication inside a WebView

Tags: authentication

I am trying to integrate with the APIs for vendors who provide Silent Network Authentication. The application that I am trying to build is mostly a WebView, that will be launched from an iOS and Android app. I know SNA does not work inside a web page just yet, so I was wondering if I will be stuck trying to get this working inside a WebView or whether I need to build some kind of bridge over the native application. I tried to find code samples but no luck thus far.